# Проблема с htpasswd

Tags: nginx

Мне надо сделать на путь админки форума XenForo, а именно /admin.php. Доп авторизацию через htpasswd конфиг ниже

```
server {

    server_name forum****;
    listen 80;
    root    /var/www/html/forum;
    index   index.php index.html;
    auth_basic "Авторизация";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd;

    location /admin\.php {
        auth_basic on;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
        auth_basic off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    auth_basic off;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Но, оно не работает, когда я захожу в админку и пароль не просит, чисто для теста я сделал просто /admin и у меня он попросил пароль. Ещё надо учесть то, что бывают такие пути в админке: /admin.php?payment-profiles/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил добавив следующее:

```
    location ~/admin\.php$ {
    auth_basic "Enter password!";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswdd;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```